# Address change for Mutual Funds, Demat and NPS in India

Tags: india, mutual-funds

Does it mandatory to submit three address change forms for the DEMAT, NPS and MF's? Since all the three data is maintained by cvlkra under the same PAN and the form is also same.

Answer (score 1):

cvlkra is an entity that only facilitates the KYC. It would forward the KYC related documents to different entities downstream and from a process point of view it would make it simple to get 3 set of documents that get forwarded to 3 entities.